# Restrict joomla 1.5 manager from accessing componets

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla1.5

I want to ***restrict*** components to access by Manager role in Joomla 1.5.

And it will be good if it is possible by just some line of code rather using any component / extension.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to achieve access control levels with just a few lines of code. If it was that simple, ACL would not be such a big deal.

You need an extension that allows you to manage the admin access levels. Take a look at these -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/13524

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/2587

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/9040 - there is also a more advanced pro version as well

Each of these should give you the control you need.

Comment: Thanks .. I think it wont be done without using one of the extension you suggest !!

Answer (score 1):

As you want to user custom coding to restrict components for manager only. 
so open the file administrator/modules/mod_menu/helper.php

On line number 167. there is a foreach for components.

```
        $login_user = JFactory::getUser(); // <--------------object for login user------------------------->
        foreach ($comps as $row)
        {
            if ($editAllComponents | $user->authorize('administration', 'edit', 'components', $row->option))
            {
                if ($row->parent == 0 && (trim($row->admin_menu_link) || array_key_exists($row->id, $subs)))
                {

                  if($login_user->gid == '23') // <--------------check for manager-------------------------> 
                    {


                    $text = $lang->hasKey($row->option) ? JText::_($row->option) : $row->name;
                     if($text == 'Banner' or $text == 'Polls' )  // <--------------write component name which is visibal to manager only-------------------------> 
            {
                    $link = $row->admin_menu_link ? "index.php?$row->admin_menu_link" : "index.php?option=$row->option";
                    if (array_key_exists($row->id, $subs)) {
                        $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode($text, $link, $row->admin_menu_img), true);
                        foreach ($subs[$row->id] as $sub) {
                            $key  = $row->option.'.'.$sub->name;
                            $text = $lang->hasKey($key) ? JText::_($key) : $sub->name;
                            $link = $sub->admin_menu_link ? "index.php?$sub->admin_menu_link" : null;
                            $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode($text, $link, $sub->admin_menu_img));
                        }
                        $menu->getParent();
                    } else {
                        $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode($text, $link, $row->admin_menu_img));
                    }

                }
                }else  // <--------------else for other group-------------------------> 
                {
                // no change in it


                    $text = $lang->hasKey($row->option) ? JText::_($row->option) : $row->name;
                    $link = $row->admin_menu_link ? "index.php?$row->admin_menu_link" : "index.php?option=$row->option";
                    if (array_key_exists($row->id, $subs)) {
                        $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode($text, $link, $row->admin_menu_img), true);
                        foreach ($subs[$row->id] as $sub) {
                            $key  = $row->option.'.'.$sub->name;
                            $text = $lang->hasKey($key) ? JText::_($key) : $sub->name;
                            $link = $sub->admin_menu_link ? "index.php?$sub->admin_menu_link" : null;
                            $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode($text, $link, $sub->admin_menu_img));
                        }
                        $menu->getParent();
                    } else {
                        $menu->addChild(new JMenuNode($text, $link, $row->admin_menu_img));
                    }

                }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot, Rakesh. it works great.

Please note: in my case, the code from above:
if($login_user->gid == '23')
had to be changed to
if($user->gid == '23')
as $login_user was undefined.

Also, you have add 1 extra } at the end to match the {}.